# 'datetime.date' object is not callable if assigned twice within variable

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, url, callable

I have the below code and for some reason I cannot have

`lastMonthEnd.strftime("%d") , lastMonthEnd.strftime("%b") and lastMonthEnd.strftime("%Y")` twice within a variable.

I declare the time variables.

```
today = date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonthEnd = first +  dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=-1)

lastQuaterBegin = first + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-3)
lastMonthBegin = first + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1)
```

I get the first URL without any issues

```
# Get P&L monthly
    plUrl = "https://go.xero.com/Reports/Report2.aspx?"\
                "reportId=ca205001-1651-4947-bf95-9b1436926f09&report=&statement"\
                "=a22c12ce-7b22-49ff-a674-1a509552f6de&attPage=Compare%20Periods&"\
                "date="+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%d")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%b")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%Y")+\
                "&timeframe=1&periods=3&budgetID=%20&total=null&ytd=null&"\
                "&CompareDateRangePeriods=1&sortByForAccount=FormattedName&cashOnly=null"
               
    driver.get(plUrl)
```

However, when I run the code below where I have `lastMonthEnd.strftime("%d") , lastMonthEnd.strftime("%b") and lastMonthEnd.strftime("%Y")` twice within the URL I get a

> File "XXX", line 145, in module
> "toDate="+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%d")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%b")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%Y")+"&"\
>
> TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not callable

error.

```
plUrl = "https://go.xero.com/Reports/Report2.aspx?reportId=ca205001-1651-4947-bf95-9b1436926f09&report=&"\
                "statement=a22c12ce-7b22-49ff-a674-1a509552f6de&attPage=Show%20Date%20Range&"\
                "date="+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%d")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%b")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%Y")+"&"\
                "timeframe=1&periods=3&budgetID=%20&total=null&ytd=null&"\
                "fromDate="+lastQuaterBegin("%d")+"%20"+lastQuaterBegin("%b")+"%20"+lastQuaterBegin("%Y")+"&"\
                "toDate="+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%d")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%b")+"%20"+lastMonthEnd.strftime("%Y")+"&"\
                "CompareDateRangePeriod=none&CompareDateRangePeriods=1&sortByForAccount=FormattedName&cashOnly=null"
                            
    driver.get(plUrl)
```

Can anyone help how to get around this?

Comment: you forgot the `strftime`, it should e.g. be `lastQuaterBegin.strftime("%d")`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm using a workaround for the topic above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to add `.strftime` on some of your `DateTime` objs.

Happy coding,
Breadberry

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm using a workaround for the topic above.